# Unable to send files via SCP

Tags: ssh, scp, amazon-ec2, hadoop

I tried using the `scp` command with the `-i` option to transfer the file from local machine to remote EC2 instance:

```
Akhis-Macbook-Pro:~ aswinakhilesh$ sudo scp -i Mykey.pem FileA ec2-user@ec2-23-20-46-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/FileA
```

Instead of the file being copied, I am getting the following message:

```
 Agent pid 2624

Akhis-Macbook-Pro:~ aswinakhilesh$ Identity added:
/home/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/id_rsa)
```

My `.ssh` folder in ec2 instance has the following files:

```
authorized_keys  
id_rsa  [Same as Mykey.pm, which is used with the -i option before]
known_hosts
```

It would be great if someone could help me out here!

Comment: `File being moved`, `scp` will copy the file and not `mv`. Also looks like your `ssh-agent` is running and your identity file gets added to it. No harm with it. Did your file copy succeed or not?

Comment: Nope, the file didn't succeed copying.

Comment: Check what all identities your `ssh-agent` is managing by `ssh-add -l`. If your `Mykey.pem ` is there, then try running `scp` without `-i` option. Can you also try if `rsync` is succeeding?

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this same issue. The solution was what someone pointed out (if you have

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

change it to

```
eval `ssh-agent' > /dev/null
```

*BUT* the important thing is that this needs to happen on the *REMOTE* host.

Answer (score 3):

What's in your .bashrc?

sshd will source .bashrc in your home directory when connecting with scp.  It would appear that you have something like `eval``ssh-agent` in that file.

If the .bashrc sends anything to STDOUT when sourced it will cause problems with scp (and likely other programs.)  There are a few different ways to deal with it, easiest is to change to:

`eval``ssh-agent` > /dev/null

You can also test if $PS1 is set to determine if it's an interactive shell, and then use conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like your destination path is not right, at least a normal user should not have right to write directly into `/home`, *however* this should result in a permission denied for the `scp` command, still you can use

instead of:
`ec2-user@ec2-23-20-46-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/FileA`

the following:
`ec2-user@ec2-23-20-46-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/`

Comment: I am afraid its giving the same result. Prints out `Identity added:
/home/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/id_rsa)`

Answer (score 0):

The connection breaks if something is printed out while running `scp`. You probably have some underlying command(s) running through `.bashrc` (or similar) while logging in to the remote host. Even for non-interactive logins, like when you're using `scp`, it will keep sourcing login scripts in the target host.

Fix this by SSHing into the remote host and checking for commands that print something. You can then try commenting them (for a quick test) or redirecting their outputs to `/dev/null` to avoid this happening next time.